# Combobox sem formatação Bootstrap / Firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

Estou usando o Bootstrap em um projeto, porém percebi que no Firefox o combobox fica sem formatação. Vejam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já no Chrome e Opera fica perfeito:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para que corrigir isso no Firefox? Vi na internet que muitos tentam customizar diretamente no CSS e com isso acaba sendo aplicado nos outros browsers.

Comment: Como está o css?

Comment: Vc customizou o estilo original do Bootstrap 3? Pq esse dropdown está completamente diferente do da documentação que fica com o design igual em todos os browsers... https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#dropdowns

Comment: Isso é do navegador. Cada navegador e até mesmo cada sistema operacional tem usa api diferente. Veja esse exemplo no w3schools. Certamente não há problema com seu css.

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_form_select&stacked=h

Comment: Olá hugocsl. Não customizei. Pois é... estranho mesmo.

Comment: Olá Leandro. O css é do próprio Bootstrap.

Comment: Olá Netinho. Exatamente. O link que você passou, no Firefox fica da mesma forma que postei.

Comment: Cara abre o link da documentação oficial que postei e olha como ele fica no firefox. Se continuar estranho te sugiro atualizar o seu Firefox que já deve estar bem ultrapassado. O que tb é estranho é que mesmo no Chrome o seu combobox parece mais o do Material Design do que o original do Bootstrap, então alguma coisa de CSS com certeza está influenciando no seu inputo, ou vc está com o CDN ou arquivo .css errado

Comment: @hugocsl, certeza que este estilo é padrão em todos os navegadores?! Estou utilizando o bootstrap no Firefox Quantum no Linux Ubuntu e o select fica realmente igual ao da foto dele, com a seta com o fundo cinza.

Comment: Hugo, na verdade estou usando o Firefox Quantum 60.0.2. Acredito que é a última versão do Firefox. Se tiver o Firefox instalado, dá uma olhada no link que o @NetinhoSantos enviou.

Comment: @Leandro cada user-agent de cada browser estiliza o select da sua forma particular, assim como outros vários elementos, como o radio button, checkbox, range, e até o scroll da janela. O que acontece é que o Bootstrap NÃO usa a tag select para fazer o dropdown, na verdade eles usam uma lista UL LI para construir esse "componente" justamente pela dificuldade de manter o estilo crossbrowser. Depois da uma olhada na resposta que dei abaixo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja o que diz a Documentação Oficial do Bootstrap 3 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#input-groups

> Avoid using `<select>` elements here as they cannot be fully styled in WebKit browsers.

*"Evite usar o elemento `<select>`, pois ele não pode ser totalmente estilizado em browsers webkit"*

Repare que justamente por isso o *combobox* da documentação é feito com uma lista não ordenada `<ul>` e `<li>` e não com a tag `<select>`

Essa é a forma correta de ser fazer o *combobox* segundo a documentação oficial https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#dropdowns-example

```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
          Dropdown
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**OBS:** Não estou falando que construir o `select` usando lista é o ideal, só estou falando que é a forma que o Bootstrap faz pois ele consegue assim controlar melhor o design do elemento. Já com a tag `select` o Bootstrap não consegue estilizar totalmente o elemento

---

Se vc quiser usar o  dentro do BS3 e ainda assim controlar a aparência do elemento vc vai ter que fazer um estilo customizado na mão. Mesmo assim ele não é totalmente *crossbrowser*

Veja um exemplo:

```css
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    select.form-control {
        padding-right: 25px;
        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='14px' height='14px' viewBox='0 0 1200 1000' fill='rgb(51,51,51)'> <path d='M1100 411l-198 -199l-353 353l-353 -353l-197 199l551 551z'/> </svg>");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: calc(100% - 7px) 50%;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="container">
    <br>
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="test" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                Test
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select id="test" class="form-control">
                    <option>(select)</option>
                    <option>(select)</option>
                    <option>(select)</option>
                    <option>(select)</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Legal Hugo, não sabia que o bootstrap fazia o select assim com li's.

Comment: @Leandro Usando o exemplo não oficial da W3School não tem como manter o padrão. O Bootstrap preza por manter o layout padrão em todas as plataformas, por isso eles nem usam o select nos componentes oficiais. Para fazer essa adaptação vc vai ter que contruir um CSS a parte.

Comment: Interessante @hugocsl. Também não sabia que o Bootstrap fazia com listas. Para ser sincero, front-end não é muito meu forte. Vou aplicar seu exemplo. Obrigado.

Comment: @Fox.11 alguns elementos são mais chatos de customizar pq cada useragent de cada browser aplica seus estilos default, como no caso do select. Mas que bom que o exemplo te serviu tmj

Answer (score 1):

O campo SELECT varia de acordo com o navegador que o visitante está utlizando. Você pode utilizar alguns métodos para criar uma configuração personalizada para o campo.

Método com CSS "appearance"
Considerado o método mais "correto" por utilizar somente o css diretamente no campo SELECT, seu maior problema se deve ao fato de ser suportado por apenas alguns navegadores (Chrome, Firefox e Safari), não tendo efeitos nos demais navegadores.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs.: Depois acesse a página com algum dos navegadores citados acima.