# Como estilizar o select dessa forma?

Tags: css3

[image: imagem modelo da estilização]
Como estilizar um select dessa forma? o designer está usando o Bulma framework nesse projeto mas não encontrei modelos desse select na documentação, tentei desenvolver por aqui mas não ficou legal alguém sabe como faz essa personalização ?

Comment: Edita a pergunta e inclui o código com o que você tentou.

Comment: cara eu tentei colocar um select dentro do outro de determinei um border-radius mas não fica nem perto dessa estilização ai...

Comment: Cara muito provavelmente isso não é um `<select>`. Veja aqui essa pergunta que tem algumas coisas que podem te interessar. Apesar de no exemplo dessa resposta ser com Bootstrap acredito que nesse framework a ideia é a mesma. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/308705/combobox-sem-formata%C3%A7%C3%A3o-bootstrap-firefox/308736#308736

Comment: Certo vou dar uma olhada melhor na documentação do Bulma, entendi as dificuldades de estilização do Select. vlw

Comment: Bom eu acabei fazendo com inputs mesmo, e pra criar esse efeito tipo de encaixe como se fosse um elemento só, eu utilizei border radius personalizado pra cada elemento, obrigado pela ajuda  @hugocsl.